# Synonym proposal: [mozilla-jetpack] -> [jetpack]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I noticed that there are two tags being used for Mozilla's Jetpack API (a.k.a. Add-on SDK): [jetpack](/questions/tagged/jetpack) and [mozilla-jetpack](/questions/tagged/mozilla-jetpack). Both are used exclusively for the Jetpack API, with the shorter variant being more popular (49 vs. 26 questions). Most [mozilla-jetpack](/questions/tagged/mozilla-jetpack) questions actually have the [jetpack](/questions/tagged/jetpack) tag as well. So I propose merging them and making [mozilla-jetpack](/questions/tagged/mozilla-jetpack) a synonym of [jetpack](/questions/tagged/jetpack). I would have proposed it through the usual UI but I don't have the necessary score (in fact, only two people do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I merged and set up a synonym there.

Comment: I see a merge but no synonym, [tag:mozilla-jetpack] still exists as an independent tag. Sorry if I'm being impatient :)